# How to explain this is not duplicate question?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

If my question is marked as duplicate, then how could I explain that my question is different by the previous one?  And lift the duplicate market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you believe that your question is not a duplicate then the first thing to do is to edit it in order to clarify what makes it distinct from the duplicate question.  Basically you should be telling us why the answers on that question do not work or why your question is not the same.

By editing your question it will go into a review queue to be reopened.  If users agree that your question should be reopened then it will be.

Be mindful though that you will have to very clearly show *why* the other answers are not helpful, show us what you have tried and why the results were not what you wanted. If many people believe that your question is still a duplicate then it will remain closed.

If you believe that your question has be closed maliciously or are absolutely adamant that your question is *100% different* then you can flag it for moderator attention.

If you are referring to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/858902/change-the-position-of-logon-screen-picture-box-in-win7) (<sup>10k only</sup>) then I agree with the initial duplicate closure, though I am interested to see if it can be reopened.  At this point it is now up to you to tell us why the solution proposed in the duplicate question is either wrong or unusable.  Not all GUI modifications can be achieved without modifying executables in the system and I strongly suspect this is one of those cases.  If you have any evidence to the contrary then it would be useful for you to share it.

Comment: Specific to the one linked, the user posted "this question is already answered but want some better solution..." sounds like the perfect reason to post a bounty on the existing one. Anyone remember those? ;)